# Is there a cleaner way to use angular ui nested routes with ui-router?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm getting into Angular and have found several great uses for it. I built a custom navigation for a client using the Angular UI-Router. It's very straight forward, but I'm wondering if there's a "cleaner" simplified way to do this.

Here's is my my code I'm currently using:

```
angular.module('website', ['ui.state']).     
config(function($stateProvider, $routeProvider){
$stateProvider
    .state('index', {
        url: "", // root route
        views: {
            "viewA": {
                templateUrl: "partials/home.html"
            },

        }
    })
    .state('route1', {
        url: "/route1",
        views: {
            "viewA": {
                templateUrl: "partials/sticks.html"
            },
        }
    })
    .state('route2', {
        url: "/route2",
        views: {
            "viewA": {
                templateUrl: "partials/apparel.html"
            },

        }
    })
    .state('route3', {
        url: "/route3",
        views: {
            "viewA": {
                templateUrl: "partials/bauer.html"
            },

        }
    })
     .state('route4', {
        url: "/route4",
        views: {
            "viewA": {
                templateUrl: "partials/bauer-vapor.html"
            },

        }
    })
})
```

This is only for a one level on a nested navigation. If I have several links or items in each level, this is going to be a long, cluttered piece of code. Is there a more concise, easier way to code this so I don't have a super long list of all the pages and where they're going?

I'm ok with doing it this way, I just thought there must be a better, cleaner way to do this.

Comment: It could probably be slightly condensed by using an array to define all the values passed to the .state() call, then you could use a loop over the array to make the .state calls which would sort of shorten things (depending on how long your list has really gotten), but you're still going to have a fairly confusing array to maintain I think, so this is probably still better.  I think an alternative would be to have just the main list defined then in the top level views define each of the sub-level navigation elements for that view? Just spitting ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Naming your views is optional, especially if you only have one I recommend using an unnamed view. You should probably drive deeper into the UI router wiki and guide. Also the projects main readme file has just been updated. It now shows a quick start example for nested states, which is actually a much more common used feature. Multiple named views really aren't necessary in most cases.

Essentially you'll shorten each state declaration to:

.state('route3', {
        url: "/route3"
        templateUrl: "partials/bauer.html"
})